Second derivative of energy with $k$
In solid-state physics, we often encounter the velocity operator (e.g. this post) which the eigenvalues can be written as
$$
V^\mu(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{\hbar} \frac{\partial E}{\partial k^\mu} \biggr|_{\vec{k}}
$$
Is there a physical interpretation for the second derivative of $E$ with the components of $\vec{k}$?
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial k^\mu \partial k^\nu}
$$

The effective mass.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)#General_case

Why would someone vote for "needs details or clarity"? The question is crystal (no pun intended) clear.

Thanks, @TobiasFünke can you turn that comment into a short answer?
